# Fully Independent Screensavers for Multiple Monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, screensaver

I am using dual monitors, but one of them is not used often.  It's just for monitoring CPU, RAM, and hard disk usage, clock, and some gadgets.

I really want to have a screensaver for it, which will work just on one monitor. When my mouse moves on it, it will turn off.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is this linux? If so, are the monitors two separate X sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 has good support for running fullscreen applications on separate monitors. My recommendation would be to run your media player visualizer from the monitor you are not using. The problem with having a screensaver run on your other monitor the way a normal screensaver would is that you are still using your computer so the screensaver will never initiate.